# RTD problems in VBA

Tags: vba

VBA macro updates cells(a,b)="=RTD(serv,,title,source) and then proceeds to use received value for some calculations. The problem is that (1) I do not know before hand whether source exists, so I have to guess, and (2) if the source does exists the cell often is not updated on time. (3) simply waiting doesn't help. (4) killing macro often does, but than I have to resort to manual restart.
(5) Suspending the macro run using

```
Sub Break_And_Go()

Dim Brk As String
Dim Entr    As String
Dim Esc As String

Brk = "{BREAK}"
Entr = "{ENTER}"
Esc = "{ESC}"

'   use "send key to simulate manual stop and go"
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
Application.SendKeys Esc, True
DoEvents
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Application.rtd.RestartServers
Application.rtd.RefreshData
Application.SendKeys Entr, True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
DoEvents
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
'    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "Break_And_Go", False

End Sub '    Break_And_Go
```

The above doesn't work reliably. Particularly in long loops over multiple cells indexes. Sometimes all cells are updated, sometimes some cells are left with "N/A", sometimes nothing is updated. When checked against the source visually there is often a discrepancy: source exists, while update fails.

Comment: Hi, I looked at the link you mentioned and it doesn't relates. However, the sequence: "Application.rtd.refresh, calculate" seems to work for few workbooks with bunch of RTD calls in manual even in VBA auto mode. After few workbooks updated this way it stops working. To make it work again I must close and restart the VBA code. ThisWorkbook.save doesn't do the trick. So, to go through (50-100) workbooks I have to do a lot of clicking. :( Any ideas?? Thanks. BTW, I found that adding space in RTD strings after 2-d and 3-d commas accelerates individual call update.

Answer (score 0):

for me setting Application.EnableCancelKey = value no longer works whereas it used to. Does it work for you? This could be the bug for you too

What is your status of application.calculation?
Is it a repaint issue? Try application.ScreenUpdating=true then false

Comment: Yes, Application.EnableCancelKey is irrelevant here. Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic just before the loop filling RTD calls into cells. I do not understand what do you mean by "repaint issue"? Pls, clarify. Application.ScreenUpdating is also irrelevant. I also tried to save and close workbook filled with RTD calls and than reopen it in hopes that it would update. Again, sometimes does work, sometimes doesn't. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, i was searching for issues with the Application.EnableCancelKey and misread your post. However looking at it now, 
Application.SendKeys Esc, True
will do nothing as it is disabled

Have you followed this post?
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/378302-rtd-not-updating.html

Comment: I looked at the link you mentioned and it doesn't relates.

Comment: After much experimenting, I found: 1. My RTD feeder was too slow due to inadequate memory space. Increasing it to the max allowed by app did help. 2. When nothing else works, simply closing (workbook.close save-as) and then opening the file again does the trick most of the time.